# How can we use iReport parameter in sql query column

Tags: sql, parameters, jasper-reports

In an iReport I'm using parameter in SQL query, but the parameter field is not showing in the data set. I have a fee structure table which 12 months columns for amount, I'm trying to get the desire month by passing the parameter as column, but the parameter column is not showing in the data field. Here is my query, I'm passing `FeeStructure.$P!{Months}` as a parameter column.

```
SELECT 
    StudentInformation.ID, ClassS.Class, Parents.Parents, 
    FeeCatagory.FeeCatagory, FeeStructure.$P!{Months}
FROM 
    StudentInformation 
INNER JOIN 
    ClassS ON StudentInformation.[C/Class] = ClassS.Id 
INNER JOIN 
    Parents ON StudentInformation.ParentID = Parents.ID 
INNER JOIN 
    FeeStructure ON ClassS.Id = FeeStructure.ClassID AND Parents.ID = FeeStructure.ParentID 
INNER JOIN  
    FeeCatagory ON FeeStructure.CatagoryID = FeeCatagory.ID 
WHERE 
    Class = $P{ClassID} 
    AND Parents = $P{Parent} 
    AND StudentInformation.ID = $P{StudentID} 
ORDER BY 
    FeeCatagory
```

Comment: thank you @Alex K code worked to me fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plz check with this.

`$P!{Months}` for this parameter give any month name as default value

and also use aliasing

```
  FeeStructure.$P!{Months} as month
```

instead of

```
  FeeStructure.$P!{Months}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?, and what is default value of `$P!{Months}`

Comment: My default value is jun. the query is running at run time but the parameter column i not showing in Field data. so i cannot drag and drop it in the report. Also in query design window when i click read Fields, its show error SQL Server Exception incorrect syntex near keyword 'null'. it is taking parameter as null.

Comment: I solve my problem using Jasper Studio, using Default value. this option is not working in iReport. Thank you for your Help.

Comment: @AqeelHaider if u use aliasing `as` it will show in fields, and from there u can drag and drop.